# How to get the timestamp of remote file in SFTP and compare it to the timestamp of the local version of the file?

Tags: bash, timestamp, sftp, ls, stat

I want to compare the timestamp of a file on remote server and the same file on local machine, so that if the remote file is not updated recently I do not need to download it to local machine. On local machine I can use the stat command to get the timestamp and do the comparison. SFTP does not have the stat command to get the timestamp of remote files. I can use ls -l in sftp, but how to do the comparison with the local file time?

Comment: **If** you can access the remote system via `ssh`, then I recommend that you consider using `rsync`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have sftp access to the remote system.